# Ajax, PHP, Javascript to Pull Values from Database after Combo Box Selection

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, combobox, selection

I have a page with Ajax, PHP, and Javascript. On that page, I have a selection/combo box of websites. When the user selects a website, I have it calling a javascript function which uses Ajax and the GET method to send to a PHP file and execute the PHP code. That PHP file, I have connecting to a database (using the users website selection to pull a specific row). I want to then send some details stored in the database (about the website the user selected) and use them on the page to run some other PHP code.

I can't seem to get it to work with the code I have and I've tried everything I can think of.

**Selection box code calling javascript function:**

```
<select name="website" onchange="doSomething(this.value)" />
<option>option 1</option>
<option>option 2</option>
<option>etc.</option>
</select>
```

**Javascript function using Ajax to call a PHP file:**

```
function doSomething(str)
{
if (str == "")
{
 document.getElementById("DIVdisplayID").innerHTML="Nothing Selected";
 return;
}
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("DIVdisplayID").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","URLHERETOPHPFILEHERE?website="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();

}
```

**My Display DIV:**

```
<div id="DIVdisplayID"></div>
```

**PHP File to access database info based off the website the user selected:**

```
<?php
$website=$_GET["q"];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("database", $con);

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Websites
WHERE WebsiteURL='$website'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo $row['WebsiteDetail1'] . " " . $row['WebsiteDetail2'];
echo "<br />";
}

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery.

doSomething(this.value) doesn't work.

```
doSomething(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text))
```

or

`doSomething($(this).val())` with jquery

All the javascript can be replaced with

```
$.get("URLHERETOPHPFILEHERE?website="+str, function(data){
    $('#DIVdisplayID').html(data);
});
```

I'm assuming "URLHERETOPHPFILEHERE" is actually replaced in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your this line of code with:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","URLHERETOPHPFILEHERE?website="+str,true);
```

replace with:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","your php file name with .php extension ?website="+str,true);
```

and in php file where you are using get method use the name in get method"website":
like:

```
$website=$_GET["website"];
```

Comment: ^ I'm confused, that's exactly what I have.